# Восстановление MySQL БД 3,6 гб занимает 1 час

Tags: mysql, резервное-копирование, dump

БД **innodb**. MySQL 5.7.13-6 (**percona server**)

Запускаю таким образом БД 3,6 гб,

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < /path/to/dump.sql
```

которая была создана так:

```
    mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --ignore-table=db12.table1 
--ignore-table=db12.table2 -u root -pasdf2ASdfdf122 db12 > /tmp/db.sql
```

И восстановление заняло около 1,5 часа!! Сервер совершенно ничем не загружен. 0 процессов, кроме mysql.

Что делать, как ускорить, подскажите, пожалуйста?

---

**обновление:**

Удалось добиться 50 минут!

Был изменён конфиг файл на:

```
tmp-table-size                 = 128M
max-heap-table-size            = 128M
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 4
```

Comment: мало деталей. движок бд (myisam/innodb), версия mysql, сайт под нагрузкой, или ты можешь бэкапы делать в оффлайне. мало деталей.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167522/innodb-takes-over-an-hour-to-import-600mb-file-myisam-in-a-few-minutes вот тут. поскольку инсерт у тебя оптимизирован наглухо, оптимизировать надо сервер.

Comment: наверняка еще что-то подкрутить можно

Comment: вопрос еще актуален?

Comment: да, вопрос актуален

Comment: Можно ли изменить формат бекапа ?  Я смотрю в сторону последующего LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: @Jenkamen Достаточно большой прирост скорости дает innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
Также стоило бы указать конфиг mysql. Или написать, что он дефолтный, кроме параметров в посте.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить переменную max_allowed_packet в 256Mb

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=256M -u root -p < "database-file.sql"
```

Comment: Добавьте в ваш ответ пояснение. Что даст предложенное вами решение.

Answer (score 1):

Перестаньте пользоваться mysqldump. Есть же Percona XtraBackup  Вот статья на habr https://habrahabr.ru/company/centosadmin/blog/229731/  Вот официальная документация https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html

Бэкапы будут происходить на горячую и без локов, а восстановление резко быстрее. Но с myisam пользы особой нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы говорим о загрузке баз InnoDB, то можно временно ускорить восстановление БД отказавшись от соответствия требованиям [ACID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) и приняв возможность утери данных при нештатном выключении сервера следующими двумя директивами:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
sync_binlog = 0
```

[Первая директива](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) говорит о том, что запись данных на диск будет происходить не сразу, а лишь время от времени, без гарантий. Это значит что если сервер выключить в один момент, то данные транзакций за последние мгновения (что-то вроде секунды) будут утеряны безвозвратно. Потому в общем случае эти опции имеет смысл использовать только временно и только для ускорения восстановления данных.

(Вторая директива развязывает руки MySQL, разрешая не фиксировать данные на диске из бинарного лога, что тоже может привести к потере данных.)